# Check if customer has purchased 5 specific items

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I would like to check and see if a customer has bought 3 particular items. If the customer has bought the items I want to reset the counter back to zero for all items for that customer. The items needed to be purchased are 1, 2, and 3.

```
CustomerID |  Item# |  TimesPurchased
1          | 1      | 2
1          | 2      | 1
1          | 3      | 1
1          | 4      | 1
2          | 1      | 1
2          | 1      | 1
```

In this example, customer 1 has purchased all of the items required. I would like to reset the TimesPurchased column back to 0 for all 3 items only for this customer. I would like the result to look like this:

```
CustomerID |  Item# |  TimesPurchased
1          | 1      | 0
1          | 2      | 0
1          | 3      | 0
1          | 4      | 1
2          | 1      | 1
2          | 1      | 1
```

I'm struggling with how to structure a query that pulls up a customer who has purchased all three items. How is this done? Also, there is a 4th item that I don't want to reset the value for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can determine the customers who have purchased the three items with:

```
select customerid
from purchases 
where itemid in (1,2, 3)
group by customerid
having count(distinct itemid) = 3;
```

You can then incorporate this into an `update`:

```
update p
    set timespurchased = 0
    from purchases p join
         (select customerid
          from purchases 
          where itemid in (1,2, 3)
          group by customerid
          having count(distinct itemid) = 3
         ) c
         on p.customerid = c.customerid;
```

Comment: In the first select statement why can't I add another column? Or how would I add another column? 

Also, how could I add an additional argument in the update clause?

Comment: @user3666520 . . . The first query is an aggregation query.  To add more columns, you either need to add them both to the `select` and `group by` or use aggregation functions such as `min()`, `max()`, and `sum()`.

Comment: I found that this query resets the times purchased to 0, but then it keeps resetting to 0 over and over again despite the fact that the times purchased column is set to 0 after the initial reset. I think this is because it is seeing the appropriate number of rows, but it doesn't take into account that they're zeroes not ones.

Comment: @user3666520 . . . Perhaps you want some filter in the subquery.  Your question isn't clear on what to do *after* the values have been set the first time.  Perhaps you should ask another question, with more details.

Comment: Nevermind, I was able to tweak the statement to include requiring the times purchased column to = 1 based on what you said in your last comment. This then requires distinct times purchased = 1 to get a count. If I run it once it works. If I run it twice it does nothing, which is what I want. Thanks for your help.